# How can I disable The Exchange in The Sims 3?

Tags: ps3, the-sims-3

I've been playing The Sims 3 on my PS3 (I mention the specific system because the options might be different). Whenever I go into the Build & Buy menu and go into specific categories, the crap that it keeps re-downloading from The Exchange over and over is *really* slowing down my game and, frankly, it's kind of pissing me off.

I've looked through the Options menu and didn't see anything in there to disable it; the only thing that really mentioned The Exchange was a big Redeem Codes button which didn't look useful at all. Is there any way to completely disable The Exchange **within the game** so I don't have to keep turning my Internet connection on and off, or is disabling the Internet the only way to keep it from downloading things constantly?

Comment: Maybe try signing out of PSN? Easier than disabling internet connection

Answer (score 1):

We couldn't disable the exchange either but we just turned off our PSN. It really did help and our Sims 3 is a lot faster now. I think it will help you too.